# Problem with node modules and Global CSS - nextjs

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I'm migrating a project made in create react app to nextjs and I ran into this problem

```
./node_modules/react-bootstrap-submenu/src/index.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm
Location: node_modules\react-bootstrap-submenu\dist\DropdownSubmenu.js
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: You probably should do what Next.js suggested: "Reach out to the maintainer and ask for them to publish a compiled version of their dependency." As it looks now **react-bootstrap-submenu** is not compatible with Next.js

Answer (score 0):

[Document](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules)

Since Next.js 9.5.4, importing a CSS file from node_modules is permitted anywhere in your application.

For global stylesheets, like bootstrap or nprogress, you should import the file inside pages/_app.js. For example:

```js
// pages/_app.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

If this solution doesn't work for you, consider the solutions below.

1. Copy css file to `public/static`.
2. and then

```
// pages/_app.js
import 'public/static/bootstrap.css'
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it didn't work.